# How to remove duplicate observations in Stata

Tags: duplicates, stata

Let's say I have the following data:

```
id  disease
1   0
1   1
1   0
2   0
2   1
3   0
4   0
4   0
```

I would like to remove the duplicate observations in Stata. 
For example

```
id   disease
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      0
```

For group `id`=1, keep observation 2

For group `id`=2, keep observation 2

For group `id`=3, keep observation 1 (because it has only 1 obs)

For group `id`=4, keep observation 1 (or any of them but one obs)

I am trying Stata `duplicates` command,

```
duplicates tag id if disease==0, generate(info)
drop if info==1
```

but it's not working as I required.

Comment: Thanks for specifying code in an edit. If you like the answer, you can accept it and gain some reputation thereby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no surprise that `duplicates` does not do what you are wanting, as it does not fit your problem. For example, the observation with `id == 2, disease == 0` is not a duplicate of any other observation. More generally, `duplicates` does not purport to be a general-purpose command for dropping observations you don't want.

Your criteria appear to be

1. Keep one observation for each `id`.
2. If `id` has any observation with value of `1`, that is to be kept.

A solution to that is

```
bysort id (disease) : keep if _n == _N
```

That keeps the last observation for each distinct `id`: after sorting within `id` on `disease` observations with the disease are necessarily at the end of each group.